# Getting element from nested list by 'random'

Tags: python-3.x

The idea is to print `name_1`, `name_2` or `name_3` by `random`.

```py
list = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]

random.choice(list)
```

There is a nested list so if I use random.choice(list) the result will be...
 'name_1', 0, 0, 0 
or 
'name_2', 0, 0, 0 
or 
'name_3', 0, 0, 0 
... however I want 'name_1', 'name_2' or 'name_3' only.

#### Thanks for answer. However I have another issue.

If I have the same list...
list = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]

... How can I make a 'for' loop for 'name' elements only (so list[0][0], list[1][0] and list [2][0])?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `random.choice(list)` will return the whole sublist (eg `['name_2', 0, 0, 0]`. You know the name are at the start of the sublist, so you can just get the `0`th index of `random.choice`'s ouput:

```py
random.choice(list)[0]
# example output: 'name_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to select only the first item of the sublists at random, so we make a list out of the first items and do `random.choice` on that list.

Or we can just choose the first element once we choose a random sublist via
`random.choice`

```
import random
list = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]
#Option 1
print(random.choice([item[0] for item in list]))
#Option 2
print(random.choice(list)[0])
```

Comment: You are uselessly computing all the names, you just to select an item randomly then get the first element of the randomly chosen item

Comment: I added both solutions just now. Thanks for the suggestion